# How to interpret the following linear programing problem?

Tags: linear-programming

My problem is simple, if I have:

$W = 8w_1 +24w_2$

restricted by:

$2w_1-3w_2≥-5$

$-4w_1+3w_2≥-15$

$w_1, w_2≥0$

The simplex table is easy, just one iteration after multiplying the restrictions by $-1$ but I don't know what to say about the problem since the solution is $w_1 = 0, w_2 = 0, s_1 = 5, s_2 = 15, W = 0$. It has no solutions? Or it does but it's just $0$?

Answer (score 1):

This is trivial as the lower bound  of the objective functional is $0$ and $(w_1, w_2)=(0,0)$ satisfies the constraints. This means that $(0,0)$ is your desired solution.